# Fijar elemento aunque el contenido del contenedor sea variable CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo unas cards donde se puede ingresar diferentes datos. Uno de ellos son los hobbie donde no siempre ocupan la misma cantidad de lineas, pero debajo de ellos tengo dos botones. Cuando se escribe menos en hobbie los botones quedan mas arriba, quiero lograr que todos queden en la misma posición, alguna idea?

Mi css:

```
.btndiv{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

button{
    background-color: #7c3c8b;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.83);
    transition: 1.5s;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Asi me queda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria asi, , los botones deben ser absolutos de posicion y botton 0 y su padre debe ser relativo

```css
.flex-column{
  display-flex:flex-column
}
.tarjet{
  height:120px;
    margin-right: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  position:relative
}
.flex{
  display:flex
}

.content-buttons{
  position:absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="tarjet flex-column">
    <div>aqui va contexndios</div> <div>aqui va contexndios</div>
     <div>aqui va contexndios</div>
     <div>aqui va contexndios</div>
   <div class="content-buttons">mis bottones</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="tarjet flex-column">
    <div>aqui va contexndios</div> 
   
     
   <div class="content-buttons">mis bottones</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que tus botones queden abajo debes definierles una posicion absoluta y ponerles un bottom:0px para que se mantengan abajo, el padre de ellos debe ser posicion relativa para que no se salgan de el

```
    .btndiv{
   position: absolute;
    bottom:0px
}
```

ya una vez ese contender se fije abajo ya puedes crear otro flexible para que tus botones se separen

aqui te dejo un ejemplo completo

```
    <div class="flex">
  <div class="tarjet flex-column">
    <div>aqui va contexndios</div> <div>aqui va contexndios</div>
     <div>aqui va contexndios</div>
     <div>aqui va contexndios</div>
   <div class="content-buttons">mis bottones</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="tarjet flex-column">
    <div>aqui va contexndios</div> 
   
     
   <div class="content-buttons">mis bottones</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
    .flex-column{
  display-flex:flex-column
}
.tarjet{
  height:120px;
    margin-right: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  position:relative
}
.flex{
  display:flex
}

.content-buttons{
  position:absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Gracias a todos :D! Lo pude solucionar

Comment: Eso esta mucho mejor jaja